# how to get array of object instead of object in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

can you please tell me how to get `array of objects` instead of `object` in angular 2.I am hitting  a service and getting a `object` as a response .

```
getUsers(): Observable<HttpResponse<UserModel>> {
    return this.http.get<HttpResponse<UserModel>>(this.configUrl).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

getting response this

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 3,
  "total": 12,
  "total_pages": 4,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "George",
      "last_name": "Bluth",
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Janet",
      "last_name": "Weaver",
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "Emma",
      "last_name": "Wong",
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

currently I am sending `whole object to my component` .Now I want to send only `data` array to my component .

currently I am receiving like this `response.data`.

```
this.userDetail.getUsers().subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.users = response.data;
    },
```

But I want to insert `this.users=response`

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4pkct8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuserdetail.service.ts

I want to manipulate the response and send `array` to component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator to extract the data array from the original response. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugunva) for a demo.

**Models**:

```
export interface UserModelResponse {
  page: number;
  per_page: number;
  total: number;
  total_pages: number;
  data: Array<UserModel>
}

export interface UserModel {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  avatar: string;
}
```

**Service**:

```
getUsers(): Observable<Array<UserModel>> {
  return this.http.get<UserModelResponse>(this.configUrl).pipe(
    map(x => x.data),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

**Component**:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.userDetail.getUsers().subscribe((response: Array<UserModel>) => {
    console.log(response);
    this.users = response;
  }, (error) => {
    console.log('error', error);
  }, () => {
    console.log('complete');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform the result from the `getUsers` method:

```
 getUsers(): Observable<UserModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<UserModelPage>(this.configUrl)
    .pipe(map(res => res.data), catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

with `map`:

```
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

where `UserModelPage` is something like this:

```
interface UserModelPage {
  data: UserModel[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would change in your **user-detail.service.ts**

```
getUsers(): Observable<HttpResponse<UserModel>> {
    return this.http.get<HttpResponse<UserModel>>(this.configUrl).pipe( 
      map((res:any) => {
        return res.data;
        })
    );
  }
```

and the following would change in your **app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userDetail.getUsers().subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.users = response;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('error', error);
    }, () => {
      console.log('complete');
    });
  }
```

I included a working representation [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urbn6s?file=src/app/app.component.ts) in case you might need it.